# How is the FXM bundle beacon constructed?

Tags: configuration, fxm

I am trying to implement FXM for a customer, with the purpose of collecting data from a bunch of WordPress based sites into a single repository.

An example of such a site is http://dev.verum.se/test/test1.php

The customer has had other people implement the beacon on the page, so how that has been done is beyond my scope. As far as I can tell, the implementation of the beacon is OK, though.

Even though the test page above is extremely simplified, I still get script errors from the beacon.

As far as I can tell, the beacon JS rendered by the server is broken. The last line of the script looks like a duplicate.

I assume that this problem occurs because part of the bundling logic for this script is misconfigured. I have been looking around the config files, but so far, I have failed to find a place that specifies how bundling should be performed.

**My question:** Where are the settings that control the contents of the FXM beacon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The beacon is created by taking a series of scripts and 'bundeling' them together (minifying and caching them).

Have a look in `App_Config\Include\FXM\Sitecore.FXM.Bundle.config` .. this shows all the parts that go into the 'bundeling' process.

This is the place you can add or modify any extra scripts you need to be delivered to the client as part of the beacon.

Comment: This was what I thought I was looking for. Apparently, the bug must be found elsewhere, since values match my local dev environment, where the issue does not occur. I'll accept this answer all the same, try to figure out a better question next :-|

Comment: thanks Stephen, that was something totally new to me. Going to take a look at it!